# Test class error for callout method, System.JSONException

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, httpcalloutmock, rest-service

I am only calling my method in Test Class and getting :
System.JSONException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed at input location [1,2]

My callout method is:

```
global static String call() {

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(reqbody);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
    HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
    deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class); // getting error here
    return resp1.access_token;
}    

global static HttpResponse createLead() {

    call();
     // some codes here
    return res1;
}
```

Callout mock class

```
@isTest 
global class PostCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('00Q7F0000043uPJUAY');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response; 
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest public with sharing class LeadManupilatorTest {
    @isTest static void testPostCallout() {
        // Set mock callout class 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new PostCalloutMock()); 
        // This causes a fake response to be sent
        // from the class that implements HttpCalloutMock. 
        HttpResponse response = LeadManupilatorServiceCallout.createLead();
        // Verify that the response received contains fake values
        String contentType = response.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String actualValue = response.getBody();
        System.debug(response.getBody());
        String expectedValue = '00Q7F0000043uPJUAY';
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include the relevant test code. The problem is in your mock.

Comment: Included test code please help

Comment: You still have not included your mock. Also please avoid supplications for help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is pretty straightforward. If you know anything about JSON, the issue should be obvious.

You're telling Salesforce that your mock response's body is going to be formatted as JSON, and then you provide `'00Q7F0000043uPJUAY'` as the input (which is not valid JSON).

According to [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), valid JSON starts and ends with either square or curly braces. At the minimum, you would need to adjust your mock body to be `{<key name>:<value>}` to conform to the JSON specs (you can't just have a string hanging out in the middle of nowhere, you need a key-value pair).

`<key>` must be a string (i.e. `"key label"`) and `<value>` can be a string, number, boolean, or `null`. In this case, your value is a Salesforce Id, and should therefore be a string (enclosed in quotes).

+edit:
Once you make the necessary changes to your mock response, your test method will naturally need to change as well. It is my hope that you can figure out which changes need to be made on your own.

+edit 2:
[RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) supersedes RFC4627, and allows for a single value not contained in a JSON object or array. If Apex uses this RFC, then enclosing your id inside a pair of double quotes will be sufficient to make it valid JSON.

Of course, if you're ever in doubt, the easiest way to fix this would be to simply use `JSON.serialize()`